# How to Update value nested array in array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

Please help
I tried to edit the second myArray, and in myArray there is myArray[data] which is also an array, how do I update it??

```
var myArray= [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "item": "DONOMULYO",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "field": "satu",
                "record": "11"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "field": "dua",
                "record": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "item": "PAGAK",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "field": "satu",
                "record": "11"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "field": "dua",
                "record": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        **"id": 2,**
        "item": "BANTUR",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "field": "satu",
                **"record": "11"**
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "field": "dua",
                "record": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "item": "SUMBERMANJING WETAN",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "field": "satu",
                "record": "11"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "field": "dua",
                "record": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how to change myArray second data record?
this is my code for change update, but there all data is updated, how to change only myArray third data inside myArray[data] ??

```
//this is my code for update 
var update_array = 2;
var update_inside_array = 0;
var valnya = '12';
var arr_data_edit = myArray[update_array].data;

if(arr_data_edit[update_inside_array].id == update_inside_array){
 arr_data_edit[idfiledx].record = valnya;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

I've tried various ways, this is the last one I ran out of ideas, please help to solve this
Thank you for the help

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do, please can you provide an example of what you want your object to look like after it's been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code should work if you simply change `idfiledx` to `update_inside_array`:

```
var update_array = 2;
var update_inside_array = 0;
var valnya = '12';
var arr_data_edit = myArray[update_array].data;

if(arr_data_edit[update_inside_array].id == update_inside_array){
 arr_data_edit[update_inside_array].record = valnya;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

---

In general, I think it would probably be better to find the item to be updated (the one that has `id: 2`) regardless of its position in the array.

Here's a way to doing that using the [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of arrays:

```js
const
  myArray = [
    { "id": 0, "item": "DONOMULYO", "data": [
      { "id": 0, "field": "satu", "record": "11" },
      { "id": 1, "field": "dua",  "record":  ""  }
    ]},
    { "id": 1, "item": "PAGAK", "data": [
      { "id": 0, "field": "satu", "record": "11" },
      { "id": 1, "field": "dua",  "record":  ""  }
    ]},
    { "id": 2, "item": "BANTUR", "data": [
      { "id": 0, "field": "satu", "record": "11" },
      { "id": 1, "field": "dua",  "record":  ""  }
    ]},
    { "id": 3, "item": "SUMBERMANJING WETAN", "data": [
      { "id": 0, "field": "satu", "record": "11" },
      { "id": 1, "field": "dua",  "record":  ""  }
    ]}
  ],
  outerId = 2,
  innerId = 0,
  newVal = '12',
  outerObj = myArray.find(obj => obj.id == outerId),
  innerObj = outerObj.data.find(obj => obj.id == innerId);
innerObj.record = newVal;
console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

(Btw, it doesn't look like you use or need any jQuery for this.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `jQuery`, you can use either [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), here is an example using `filter`:

```js
var update_array = 2;
var update_inside_array = 0;
var valnya = '12';

var item = myArray[update_array].data.filter(x => x.id == update_inside_array)[0];

if (typeof item !== 'undefined') item.record = valnya;

console.log(myArray);
```